Should App needs to include NDK if AAR use NDK?
I'm developing an Android SDK (AAR) using kotlin. I use some cpp code inside the Androis SDK using NDK, & CMake. Once I build the AAR, other developers will use my AAR on their own Android apps. The question is

If developers use my AAR, will they need to add NDK to their App project in Gradle?
What should I do if my AAR should work with all apps with different Gradle & NDK versions?

Thanks.

NDK is needed for your library to compile C++ and C code and use it. After you publish your library NDK is no longer needed as the code is already compiled into bundle. All you need to worry is supporting minSDK and compileSDK because that affect your library users
